# Request to AWS reveals internal server IP address

Tags: asp.net, security

When HTTP 1.0 request is sent to a website hosted on AWS in the following manner;

```
curl -v example.com --http1.0 --header 'Accept:' --header 'Connection:' --header 'Host:'
```

Server responds with the following response message:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 06:08:49 GMT
< Location: https://10.0.10.243/
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Content-Length: 137
< Connection: Close
< 
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://10.0.10.243/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
```

What should be done on AWS to prevent revealing internal IP address of the server when this type of request is received?

Comment: Why is your webserver returning a `302`? Is that intentional?

Comment: You need to do one of the two options here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=125346

Answer (score 2):

I think that it has to do less with AWS and more with the configuration of your IIS server.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967342/fix-the-internal-ip-address-of-an-iis-7-0-server-is-revealed-if-an-htt

https://scotthelme.co.uk/hardening-your-http-response-headers/#server

Answer (score 0):

In my system it returns the load balancer. I found this post explaining a bit more -

[Stop Elastic Load Balancer From Revealing Internal Private IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286569/stop-elastic-load-balancer-from-revealing-internal-private-ip)

And this also -
https://serverfault.com/questions/924733/aws-elb-returning-its-own-private-ip-address

Since it is only exposing the load balancer I suppose it is not that big of an issue.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).